# Retrieving data from mysql database after logging in

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a profile page for users. I want to be able to display data from a mysql database after the user has logged in to the website.

The PHP I've used on the member's profile page to try and retrieve the data is as follows:

```
 $link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

 if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

         die("Could not connect to database");

 }

$query = "SELECT * FROM user1 WHERE id ='$_SESSION['id']'";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

          echo "<p>Name: " .$row[name];
          echo "<p>Email: " .$row[email];
          echo "<br />".$row[band];
    }
```

If anyone has any ideas I'd be really grateful.

Comment: so what problem you are facing?

Comment: It isn't displaying the data from the database.It is just blank. "name:" and "email:" echo fine but the data from the row is just blank

Comment: @Anant Please don't spam the comments with "check my answer". By the point that you leave an answer OP will already get notified - there's no reason to tell him to check it. OPs only other question has an accepted answer so he obviously knows how to accept one and if he deems your answer the best, I'm sure he'll pick it without you nagging him.

Comment: @MikeHiggins  I am the first person who suggest you the right thing (both the problems that you have in your code not only query problem). So I think it will be me. when you tell others then they added my second point in there answers ,what I already added at the beginning. its in-appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your query to be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user1 WHERE id ='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
```

and you can read data by this, putting key between 2 `'` :

```
echo "<p>Name: " .$row['name'];
echo "<p>Email: " .$row['email'];
echo "<br />".$row['band'];
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped but the data still isn't displaying in the echo

Comment: @MikeHiggins put the the keys of array in 2 single quota, I update answer

Comment: ignore that, yes it does

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first the session id `echo $_SESSION['id'];`

may be you don't set session after user log in

Comment: I tested that and it does echo the right id number but the echo's for name, email and band still won't display the data